# VSTO Outlook before item changed event, or previous item status

Tags: outlook, vsto

I am developing a visual studio VSTO add in and monitoring item changed events for mail, contacts, tasks and appointment items. This I have done using the following

```
  //subsrribe to task events
        taskItems = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks).Items;                
        taskItems.ItemChange += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(TaskItems_ItemChange);
        taskItems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(TaskItems_ItemAdd);

        appointmentItems = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items;
        appointmentItems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(appointmentItems_ItemAdd);

        //Added back as itemchanged requested
        appointmentItems.ItemChange += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(appointmentItems_ItemChange);

        contacts = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Items;
        contacts.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(contacts_ItemAdd);
        contacts.ItemChange += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(contacts_ItemChange);
```

I need to be able to save the previous state of the item changed, but in the above event handlers all I get is the item that has changed. Ideally what I require is a 'before item' changed event, or alternatively a way of keeping track of the item a user selects in outlook and then saving the required property state (e.g category), then I can access this in the changed event handler.